# phantomjs click a link, expect ajax response Dom, but there is no response Dom

Tags: phantomjs

Use `link = document.querySelector()` to get a link, and use `link.dispatchEvent()` to trigger a mouse event which create by `ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, true);`

This link should be get some response Dom, but there wasn't.

I try some step in chrome console, it worked correctly. And I can click a link like "next page" or "search", it worked correctly too. But when I try a link with ajax and want get
some response dom, it doesn't work, and I found.

I have blocked by this three days, so ask for help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added a delay to your PhantomJS script to give the page time to execute the JavaScript associated with the click?

Comment: Yes, I tested from 5s to 60s. I also found after a ajax request following a page.onNavigationRequested, and seems this onNavigationRequested reopened the page. And I use ubuntu server 12.04.